# MATLAB: legend for plotyy with multiple data sets

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I'd like to automatically create graphs of Hardness H and Young's modulus E of samples as function of load L of indenter.

My goal is to create legend containing black circle marker labeled *Sample one*, black square labeled *Sample two* etc. Right now I get legend of default(blue) colour.

Preceeding line specifications are discussed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329087/matlab-changing-line-specifications/9329230#9329230).

Here's my actual MWE code:

```
[m,n]=size(data1); %data1 - m x 3 matrix with data for first sample.
[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy([data1(1:m,1)],[data1(1:m,2)],[data1(1:m,1)],[data1(1:m,3)]);
  %plots 1st sample data

set(h1,'linestyle','o')
set(h2,'linestyle','o')
c1=get(h1,'color);c2=get(h2,'color'); %store colors

line('parent',ax(1),'xdata','[data2(1:m,1)],'ydata',[data2(1:m,2)],...
     'color',c1,'linestyle','s') %plots 2nd sample hardness
line('parent',ax(2),'xdata','[data2(1:m,1)],'ydata',[data2(1:m,3)],...
     'color',c2,'linestyle','s') %plots 2nd sample young's modulus
```

Thanks for any approach and/or correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the handle for one of each different elements, you can use `legend` with a vector of handle and a cell of legend strings.

Example:

```
figure
hold all
for i=1:3
    h(i) = plot([i i])
end
ylim([0 4])

legend([h([1 3])], {'aa', 'cc'})
```

Comment: so you suggest "printing" third line in set `hl(i)=line...` out of limits and refer legend to it?

Comment: No, I suggest using the handles of the relevant lines in the `legend` command.

Comment: For `plotyy` use `legend(H1, {'curve1', 'curve2', ... });` and `legend(vertcat(H1, H2), {'curve1', 'curve2', ... });`